# What do you think happens when a child process executes a chdir - does this effect the parent?

Tags: c, process, fork

```
int chdir(const char *path);
```

-chdir changes the current directory to that speciﬁed in path.
if I use this command on child / Does this effect the parent ?

Please explain why (Yes/No) ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. While homework questions are welcome for guidance in an attempted solution (e.g. what explanation did you give?). Asking the question without an attempt to answer it feels like you are requesting someone else to do your homework for you.  Please attempt the answer and see what you get as a response. Meanwhile welcome to   [SO] and also when you get a chance read [ask]

Comment: This is not my homework sir.

Comment: child processes directory changed when I do that. Actually I expect the parent processes change too. But this did not happened @Flimzy

Comment: @UgurTufekci: Then you already know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The child and the parent are separate processes. For the most part, resources for the child are copied from the parent’s resources when the child is created, so they are separate resources, not shared resources.

When starting, the system creates an initial process. That processes creates additional system processes, to manage the user interfaces, to provide network services, and so on. When you log in (which may be automatic), one of those processes creates a process to manage your login session, including the desktop. When you open applications, that login/session process (or something else it creates) creates an application process.

If, when a child changed its current directory, the parent’s directory also changed, then the parent’s parent’s directory would change, and so would its parents, and then all the system processes back up the line would be using a different directory. That is not appropriate; they should not use a particular user’s directory. Each process has its own purposes for having a particular current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

In linux if you call fork() what happens is the child process just becomes a copy of the parents address space. After the new address space is set up, they are just separate processes. So when you call chdir in one process, it wont affect the other. Hope that was helpful in some way.